# How to dump CSV file contains case sensitive columns data to Cassandra DB from NIFI?

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

We have a requirement to dump the CSV file data to Cassandra DB - the file contains mixed case column names with special characters (eg:- **Actual_Values, Serial.NO, quantity**).

Created a Cassandra table with these 3 columns as such but while dumping data from NIFI through **PutCassandraRecord** processor its throwing error as **InvalidQueryException: undefined column actual_values**.

Observed NIFI by default converts the column names to lowercase and its not accepting column names defined with special characters other than underscore.

Could anyone please help to fix this issue and assist to dump the data.

Comment: Are you providing the schema to the CSVReader, or is it being inferred?

Comment: @mattyb - its being inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it's not a NiFi is doing normalization of the name, but it happens in Cassandra. By default, Cassandra [treats all identifiers (keyspace, table, column names) as case-insensitive](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/definitions.html#identifiers).  To make them case-sensitive, you can add a double quotes around keyspace and table names, like this: `"Keyspace"."Table"`.